# SQL Query Error while reading data from XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While trying to execute the following SQL query, I get the following error message:

SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML1
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML1(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Error Msg:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "D:\Test.xml" could not be opened. OPerating system error code 21 (The device is not ready.).

Comment: Is the file being opened by other editors? The file should not be opened by other apps.

Comment: its working for me. Does your sql server have access to D:\?

Comment: I tried reading the file from a desktop folder instead of D:\ drive and this time I got a different error "Operating system error code 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)."